# slow python code seems like a suitable fit for itertools: how to optimize?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have this:

```
entity_key = 'pid'
data = [ { ... }, { ... } ]
entities = list(set([ row[entity_key] for row in data ]))
parsed = []
total_keys = ['a','b','c']
for entity_id in entities:
    entity_rows = [ row for row in data if row[entity_key] == entity_id ]
    totals = { key: sum(filter(None, [ row.get(key) for row in entity_rows ])) for key in total_keys }
    totals[entity_key] = entity_id
    parsed.append(totals)
return parsed
```

In my scenario, `data` is about 30,000 items, it's large.

Each item is a `dict`, each `dict` contains the identifier `pid`, and numeric values for each item defined in `total_keys`, e.g. `{ 'pid': 5011, 'a': 3, 'b': 20, 'c': 33 }`

As you see, the code returns a list of unique rows for each `pid`, with the summed columns defined in the `total_keys` list. There may be about 800-1000 unique `pid` values, so `parsed` ends up being about 800-1000 items.

It's slow. I've tried to re-write this using `itertools.groupby` but it doesn't seem the best fit. Is there some magic I'm missing?

Comment: filter is not needed just use `sum(row[key] ... if key in row...)` that is also faster than using get, you also first create a list then a set and a list again, just use a set `entities  ={row[entity_key] for row in data}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a single dict using pids as the outer keys:

```
entity_key = 'pid'

data = [ { 'pid': 5011, 'a': 3, 'b': 20, 'c': 33 },{ 'pid': 5012, 'a': 3, 'b': 20, 'c': 33 }, 
{ 'pid': 5011, 'a': 3, 'b': 20, 'c': 33 },{ 'pid': 5012, 'a': 3, 'b': 20, 'c': 33 }]


from collections import defaultdict

totals = ["a", "b", "c"]

dfd = defaultdict(lambda: {"a":0, "b", 0, "c": 0})
for d in data:
    for k in d.keys() & totals:
        dfd[d["pid"]][k] += d[k]
```

Output will be all your pid's grouped and any a b or c key values summed:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f2cf93ed2f0>,
 {5011: {'a': 6, 'c': 66, 'b': 40}, 5012: {'a': 6, 'c': 66, 'b': 40}})
```

For python2 you need to use `uni = d.viewkeys() & totals`

If you data was actually grouped you could yield a group at a time:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def yield_d(data,k, keys):
    for k,v in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(k)):
        d = defaultdict(lambda: dict.fromkeys(keys, 0))
        for dct in v:
            for _k in dct.keys() & keys:
                d[k][_k] += dct[_k]
        yield d
```

Comment: `defaultdict` and iterating over `data` seems like a really solid solution and quite fast.

Comment: @Wells, we just do a single pass over data and then find the common keys based on totals which I think is about as little work as we can   get away with,  the runtime should be around  `O(len(data)*len(totals))`

Comment: Nice bend of the algorithm!  Just a nit: you could create your `dfd = defaultdict(lambda: {k: 0 for k in totals})` (dry-spot)

Comment: exactly what I ended up doing, @xtofl

Answer (score 2):

You've got an `O(n^2)` algorithm because of your membership test inside the loop.  If you create an indexed data structure, you can improve performance a lot.

```
entity_key = 'pid'
data = [ { ... }, { ... } ]
totals_keys = ['a','b','c']
parsed = []

indexed = {}
for row in data: # construct a map of data rows, indexed by id
    entity_id = row[entity_key]
    indexed.setdefault(entity_id, []) # start with an empty list
    indexed[entity_id].append(row)

for entity_id in entities:
    entity_rows = indexed[entity_id] # fast lookup of matching ids
    totals = { key: sum(row[key] for row in entity_rows if key in row) for key in totals_keys }
    totals[entity_key] = entity_id
    parsed.append(totals)

return parsed
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Pandas?

If you have pid as a column, looks like a good match for

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(your dictionary)

df.groupby(['pid']).sum()
```

Comment: Functionally this seems to be right, but what about performance?

Comment: @xtofl well, each column is a pandas Series, which, in turn, is a numpy array, and they are fastest option available for thing like sum, scale, etc

Comment: pandas is definitely worth looking into, I'll give it a shot